# Where is syntax error when trying invoke method?

Tags: java

I am beginner in Java. I have inherited one student class i.e student from other class `Datataking`. Both are in separate files. I created object of `Datataking` class and trying to access `takeData` method by the object but it gives syntax error. Syntax Error is at 
`StdData.takeData();`. How to Solve it?

Code is below of both Classes.

`Datataking` Class:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Datataking {

protected String FirstName, LastName, FatherName ;
protected Integer Id,Day,Month,Year;

void takeData()
{

    Scanner Input=new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Please Enter  Id = ");
    Id= Input.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Please Enter  First Name = ");
    FirstName = Input.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Please Enter  Last Name = ");
    LastName = Input.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Please Enter  Father Name = ");
    FatherName = Input.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Please Enter  Date Of Birth  ");

    System.out.print("Day = ");
    Day= Input.nextInt();

    System.out.println();

    System.out.print("Month = ");
    Month= Input.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Year = ");
    Year = Input.nextInt(); 
}

   /*###########################################*/

void printData()
{
    System.out.println("First Name = " + FirstName);

    System.out.println("Last Name = " + LastName);
    System.out.println("Father Name = " + FatherName);
    System.out.println("Date Of Birth = " + Day + "/" + Month + "/" + Year);

}


 }
```

`Student` Class:

```
   import java.util.Scanner;

   public class Student extends Datataking {

protected int Fee,ClassOfStudent;

Datataking StdData=new Datataking();

StdData.takeData();
    }
```

Comment: the call `StdData.takeData();` must happen within a block, or static block, constructor or method of `Student`.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax

Answer (score 0):

You need to invoke `takeData()` in some method body, not in class.

Comment: Thanks Alot . I'm realy out of mind not seeing such a big mistake

Answer (score 0):

When you create a class, you define variables and methods. You cannot have statements on their own. Statements must be inside a method:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Student extends Datataking {

    //variable declarations
    protected int Fee,ClassOfStudent;
    Datataking StdData=new Datataking();

    //method declarations
    //you have none

    //ILLEGAL (this is a statement)
    StdData.takeData();

}
```